# Django filter by field of related model and annotate with another field of that related model

Tags: sql, django

Say I have a models like:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Instructor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    town = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Level(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ActivityOffered(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Given a city and an activity and level, I would like to filter instructors in that city by those who have a related activityoffered with that activity and level. I think I can do this like this:

```
Instructor.objects..filter(city=city).filter(activityoffered__activity = activity, activityoffered__level = level)
```

However, I would also like to annotate the instructor by the price for that activity offered.

E.g. I would like to get a list of all instructors who offer beginners archery and what price they offer it at.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? Am I better to get a queryset of activity offered instances and then construct it from that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Q object to filter you query like this !
(don't forget to import Q)

```
q = Intructor.objects.filter(Q(city=city) and Q(activityoffered__activity=activity) and Q(activityoffered__level = level))
```

this code assume that city, activityoffered__activity,... is an respectivily object city, activity, .... if not you can use something like this:

```
q = Intructor.objects.filter(Q(city__name=city) and Q(activityoffered__activity__name=activity) and Q(activityoffered__level__name = level))
```

if you want to compare with price reference:

here i have use __lt(less than) attribute of fields in queryset

```
q = Intructor.objects.filter(Q(city__name=city) and Q(activityoffered__activity__name=activity) and Q(activityoffered__level__name = level) and Q(price__lt=price))
```

you can use __gt (greater than) or __lte(less than or equal)  or __gte(greater than or equal).

anotate (don't forget to add anotate, min or max module)
with your queryset you can do something like this:

```
Instructor.objects.anotate(min_price=Min(price)).filter(city=city).filter(activityoffered__activity = activity, activityoffered__level = level)
```

with Max you have something like this !

```
Instructor.objects.anotate(max_price=Max(price)).filter(city=city).filter(activityoffered__activity = activity, activityoffered__level = level)
```

If you want to know the price it simple you make the loop:

```
q = Instructor.objects.filter(city=city).filter(activityoffered__activity = activity, activityoffered__level = level)
for i in q:
# some code
i.price
```

It all

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using my archery example above, would this not give me instructors who do archery and also teach something at beginner level, rather than instructors who teach archery at beginner level? The query in my question already does this bit properly, its the annotating with price that I am struggling with.

Comment: ahhhhh ! okay! okay ! give me 1minutes  ! i add another answer !

Comment: if yes  you can use my answer if no what is other element reference to compare ???

Comment: Yes beginner is name of level. Lets say I have two instructors. One teaches archery at beginner level, one teaches tennis at beginner level and archery and advanced level. Your query will get me both instructors where I only want first one. It also doesn't solve price problem

Comment: I don't think you've understood. I do not want to compare to price, I want to annotate queryset by the price. Your queryset is also wrong, it should be `Instructor.objects.filter(city=city).filter(activityoffered__activity = activity, activityoffered__level = level)`

Comment: max price or min price ??? That's all i want to help you ! what type by max or min price ?

Comment: I want to know the price, not filter by it.

Comment: If you want to know the price it simple make loop because you have a filter request !

Comment: I have edited my answer i have added a loop ! Take a look!

Comment: @rakwen - This answer and follow-up conversation in comments is getting out-of-hand. This isn't a discussion forum. This is not the place for you to post "look at my updated answer" or "is it ok" with every edit. The OP already said you didn't answer the question. Either delete your answer or move on, but please stop having a conversation here in comments.